# Python TypeError '_io.TextIOWrapper' object does not support item assignment when getting data from HTML

Tags: python, json

When using flask to grab data from HTML and attempt to create a new dict with the data in a json file I am getting

```
[2018-08-04 18:48:46,700] ERROR in app: Exception on /savetask [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ninja_000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\ninja_000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\ninja_000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\ninja_000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\ninja_000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\ninja_000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "gui.py", line 33, in savetask
    task['taskid'] = str(request.form['taskid'])
TypeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object does not support item assignment
```

My Python

```
@app.route('/savetask',methods=['POST'])
def savetask():
    tasks = json.load(open('tasks/tasks.json'))
    with open("tasks/tasks.json", "w") as task:
        task['taskid'] = str(request.form['taskid'])
        task['profilename'] = str(request.form['profile'])
        json.dump(task, tasks)
    return redirect('/')
```

My JSON

```
[
    {
        "taskid": "Task 1",
        "profilename": "profile1"
    },
    {
        "taskid": "Task 2",
        "profilename": "profile2"
    }
]
```

Help is very appreciated I looked at other posts but I couldn't find an answer

Comment: So `task` is a file object, and `task['taskid'] = ...` doesn't work on such an object.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm really new to this I thought that was the way to do it, how should I achieve my goal?

Comment: So what should happen when the task id already exists?

Comment: It's meant to create a new dict within [] for example if request.form['taskid'] = 3 and request.form['profile'] = profile3 and they save I would want the json file to look like,

Comment: [
    {
        "taskid": "Task 1",
        "profilename": "profile1"
    },
    {
        "taskid": "Task 2",
        "profilename": "profile2"
    },
    {
        "taskid": "Task 3",
        "profilename": "profile3"
    }
]

Comment: Right, so then just load the JSON data from the file, create a new dictionary that you append to the list, then save the list as JSON to the file again.

Comment: I'm stuck on creating a new dict I thought that was how you do it, how should I create a new dict?

Comment: Using the above stuff

Comment: Do you know how to create a new dict, without using JSON? And do you know how to append an object to a list?

Comment: @MartijnPieters My bad I figured out how I thought there was more too it

Answer (score 0):

You can't just assign to an open file object. An open file object, even for JSON data, can't act as a mapping, so `task['taskid'] = ...` fails.

If the file contains a JSON document you need to:

- Parse the JSON data into a Python object
- Update the Python object to add the new information.
- Encode the Python object to JSON and write it back to the file.

You may have to work out what should happen when you update your list of tasks too. What should happen when a task id already exists? You need to think about the data structure; perhaps a list is not as suitable a structure, and a dictionary of `{taskid: taskdata}` is a better way of updating existing tasks.

Note that you can't do this *and* support multiple concurrent requests trying to do the same, and keep your data consistent! For example, if you reloaded your webpage while the server is still trying to encode and write to disk, then the other request would see partial data and throw an exception.

You'll need to add file locking to work around that, or write to a separate temporary location that you then move over to replace the old file; the move operation is *atomic*, in that it'll happen all at once and any other concurrent attempts to read the file will either get the old or the new version, but always as a complete file.

Worrying about concurrency may not be required for a simple homework task, but for real-world web applications this is absolutely something you need to handle. Any website that serves more than just one visitor must take into account what might happen when two or more visitors come and try to do things on your site at the same time.

So, for a working solution that won't immediately *break* when multiple people try to add tasks, you could use:

```
import os.path
import shutil
import tempfile

@app.route('/savetask', methods=['POST'])
def savetask():
    tasks_path = os.path.join(app.root_path, 'tasks/tasks.json')
    # load the JSON list
    with open(tasks_path) as tasksfile:
        tasks = json.load(tasksfile)

    # add a new task
    tasks.append({
        'taskid': request.form['taskid'],
        'profilename': request.form['profile'],
    })

    # write out the tasks to a new file, then move
    # it across to replace the old.
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(dir=os.path.dirname(tasks_path), delete=False) as temporary_file:
        json.dump(tasks, temporary_file)
    shutil.move(temporary_file.name, tasks_path)

    return redirect('/')
```

Now all you have to worry about is what will happen when two requests *at the same time* try to add a task. Do you think both will be added to your JSON file correctly, or could data go missing?